# ChartJS difficulty with X Axis and pulling appropriate data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, chart.js

I'm having some difficulties with iterating over some json data and displaying the proper X axis (Date/Time) I've tried several times to loop through the json data to extract the time for each worker in "history", but unsuccessful.

Here is a sample of the JSON - https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpoolcharts/blob/main/samplejson.json

And here is my code - https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpoolcharts/blob/main/worker_stats.js

To get it to work (somewhat), i've just thrown 48 random numbers as points on the x-axis:

```
displayWorkerHashrateGraph(Array.from(Array(48).keys()), dataset, label);
```

but obviously there are several problems with this, such as if a new worker joins after one has already been reporting, it starts at 1 and doesn't line up with the other workers.

You can see here that there is no dates/times on the x axis, and the label says 78 instead of a date label.
[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rvRo.png)

I've also tried to loop through the list of each worker and extract the time like so:

```
let labelsList = [];
let historyList = [];
    //Begin History Loop
    for (var w in workerData.history) {
        var worker = getWorkerNameFromAddress(w);
        var a = {
            key: worker,
            hashrate: []
        };
        for (var wh in workerData.history[w]) {
            a.hashrate.push([workerData.history[w][wh].time * 1000, workerData.history[w][wh].hashrate]);
            
            
             labelsList.push([w, workerData.history[w][wh].time * 1000]);
        }
        historyList.push(a);
```

But that ends up looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou311.png) - Seems its taking the time for all 3 of them, but not lining up with the hashrate and pushing all the values to the left.

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. Pull the time value for each worker iteration from the history element, regardless of when a worker starts reporting.
2. Mark the hashrate on the graph at the proper date/time
3. Only display the last hour of stats (BONUS: a way to zoom out to see all 12 hours of stats)

I'd really appreciate any help you can give, I'm a bit new to javascript and I've tried many times to achieve the above and have seriously been banging my head on a wall. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need to be more specific. What is the problem you are facing? How does the chart look like and how it should like?

Comment: With the code as-is, the x axis is just showing 1-48 because I don't know how to extract the date from each worker properly, and if a new worker shows up later it doesnt begin on the rightmost side of the chart, it begins on the left and doesnt sync with the other workers. Example - https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpoolcharts/blob/main/current_code_example.png .  I've also tried taking all the times from the json but that loops for eachj worker and makes the graph like this: https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpoolcharts/blob/main/passing_time_for_all_workers_to_labels.png